# Not able to upload images using cloudinary

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, cloudinary

I can not upload images to cloudinary, I think it has something to do with my placement of the cloudinary uploader function that being said I have tried to restructure but it still will not work.

Apologies I had missed the error off! "typeError can not read proeprty of 'path'.

```
userRouter.post('/property', upload.single('propertyImage'),passport.authenticate('jwt',{session : false}),(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.files);
    const property = new Property({
        street: req.body.street,
        town: req.body.town,
        area: req.body.area,
        PostCode: req.body.PostCode,
        NoBeds: req.body.NoBeds,
        NoBath: req.body.NoBath,
        NoLivingRooms: req.body.NoLivingRooms,
        askingPrice: req.body.askingPrice,
        propertyImage: image_url
    });
const {propertyImage} = files;
 cloudinary.uploader.upload(
      propertyImage.path,
      { folder: "/houseImage/" },
      async (error, results) => {
        const image_url = results.url;

    property.save(err=> {
        if(err)
         res.status(500).json({message : {msgBody: "Error has occured", msgError : true}});
        else{
            req.user.properties.push(property);
            
            req.user.save(err=> {
                if(err)
                 res.status(500).json({message : {msgBody: "Error has occured", msgError : true}});
                 else
                 res.status(200).json({message: {msgBody: "Successfully created property", msgError : false}});
            })
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you print what's inside `houseImage`? I'm not able to see how this variable is defined or being passed

Comment: houseImage should be named propertyImage, I had made a mistake however I still get the same errors. I also get the error of files is not defined. The propertyImage folder is just a folder in cloudinary where the images are stored.